# Passing HTML input tag value to Django view

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have an input element in my django template which has an onclick event written in javascript
 I want the updated value of this input element to pass to my view in views.py
 How to achieve this?

**Below is my HTML element**

```
<input id="minus" type="button" class="btn btn-black btn-outline-white py-3 px-4" size="5" value="-">
<input id="theInput" type="number" name="quantity" size="2" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline-black py-3 px-1" title="Qty" value="1" min="0" step="1">
<input id="plus" type="button" class="btn btn-black btn-outline-white  py-3 px-4" size="5" value="+">

<div class="py-1 bg-black ">
  <div class="row no-gutters slider-text align-items-end justify-content-center">
            <h4><a class="text"  type="button" onclick="send_value()" href="{% url 'mycart' %}/?item={{name}}&price={{price}}">Add To Cart</a></h4>
</div>
```

**Below is my script function**

```
<script>
    input = document.getElementById('theInput');
    document.getElementById('plus').onclick = function(){
      input.value = parseInt(input.value, 10) +1
    }
    document.getElementById('minus').onclick = function(){
      input.value = parseInt(input.value, 10) -1
    }
</script>
```

**Below is my views.py code**

```
def mycart(request):
  quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
  item = request.GET.get('item')
  return render(request, 'mycart.html', {'quantity': quantity,'item':item})
```

Comment: you can use ajax to send data to the backend without leaving the page.

Comment: use AJAX to send it as request to url on server.

Comment: You should use Django Forms to get input from users. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say that you want to pass to your django view the value of #theInput field :
You need to use something that will handle the value of the input and send it the server (views.py)
In that example i will use ajax.

First you need a url that will refer the ajax request to the right view.

In your urls.py

```
    path('target_view/', views.YourView)
```

Now you need to send the value to the server using ajax, you need also a button or a link to trigger the ajax post action like bellow :

```
<button onclick='send_value()'> Submit input value </button>

<script>
 function send_value(){

             $.ajax({
             url: '/target_view/',
             method : 'POST',
             data: {quantity: $('#theInput').val()},
             beforeSend: function() {
              // things to do before submit
             },
             success: function(response) {

              alert(response)
              }
              });
}
</script>
```

And than you interpret the value in your view like this :

```
@csrf_exempt
def GetInputValue(request):
  input_value = request.POST['quantity']
  return HttpResponse(input_value)
```

the `csrf_exempt` decorator is obligatory if you want to send data to server from input fields without the `{% csrf_token %}` on a form

Comment: yet unable to get the value ...on my mycart template the quantity value shows none...I have posted the code for views.py above ..please check out once

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: I just tried the code and it is working, the button that trigger the ajax request is in which page ?

Comment: in the same template below my quantity button …..just now posted that button above

Comment: There is a problem here, you are actually calling the function mycart twice in your ajax and with your button so what you have to do either you change the rendering of the page mycart.html using window.location.href in the success answer on the ajax request or you pass the quantity as available in your url like you have done with the item and the price